# Can you pull multiple Facebook profile picture sizes in one API request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

You can specify the size of the profile picture using the graph api like this:

`/me?fields=picture.type(square).width(638).height(638)`

But does anyone know how to pull multiple sizes all in one API request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the API. What you could do, if you know the picture id, is this:

```
GET /{PROFILE-PIC-ID}
{
  "id": "XXX", 
  "created_time": "2014-09-03T20:43:08+0000", 
  "from": {
    "id": "XXX", 
    "name": "XXX"
  }, 
  "height": 720, 
  "icon": "XXX", 
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 914, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 914
    }, 
    {
      "height": 720, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 720
    }, 
    {
      "height": 600, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 600
    }, 
    {
      "height": 480, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 480
    }, 
    {
      "height": 320, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 320
    }, 
    {
      "height": 540, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 540
    }, 
    {
      "height": 130, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 130
    }, 
    {
      "height": 225, 
      "source": "XXX", 
      "width": 225
    }
  ], 
  "link": "XXX", 
  "picture": "XXX", 
  "source": "XXX", 
  "updated_time": "2014-11-25T10:05:11+0000", 
  "width": 720, 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      ...
    ], 
    "paging": {
      ...
    }
  }, 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      ...
    ], 
    "paging": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**BUT** this will also mean that:

- you need the `user_photos` permission
- you need to make multiple calls (e.g. `/me/albums` ... etc) to get the profile picture id.